# How do I host multiple servers on Hyper-V with only a few public IP addresses?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I have a dedicated server, which is currently running Windows 2008 R2 Web edition and VMWare Server. I am upgrading to Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with Hyper-V. Once upgraded, it will have 24GB of RAM and a four core Core i7 processor. At the moment, it runs IIS on the main system instance, and has a Linux VM. The Linux VM has a dedicated IP given to it, and the host has 2 IPs.

Once the upgrade is complete, I would like to move the Web hosting to a VM on the machine under Hyper-V, and also move the Linux box to Hyper-V. This will mean that both VMs have a public facing IP as does the box itself. I am currently limited to 3 public facing IPv4 addresses, but have a /64 IPV6 block.

If I want multiple VMs, some public (web sites, etc) others not (development boxes) how do I do it? I know that I can just set up a reverse proxy and give that a public IP and give the resources behind it private IPs. Is that the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue - my answer was to run ISA Server as a VM too (I know this is normally frowned upon) to handle the inbound requests and route to the correct server (all using internal IP addresses).

Comment: sounds like a posibility... need to look into this. thanks for the tip.

Comment: +1. ISA (or apache with mod_proxy) are both good options to solve this issue. A reverse proxy was the first thing that came to my mind as well.

Comment: Cool. going to look into ISA and see what i can get it to do.

Comment: @TiernanO ISA has been re-branded as Forefront Threat Management Gateway (TMG). For new installations, you should be looking at that.

Answer (score 0):

You router should be able to do NAT and port forwarding.  And use the private address range for your servers.

Comment: I dont have my own router infront of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use private IP address for your servers. And you may hava a mapping between public 
and private IP address. You may to use one linux for this and its free.

In other case you may use CISCO ASA, mikrotik , TMG server . etc ..